# Android BLE for Heart Rate receiving data from Product

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am developing a code for heart rate detection using BLE. I am able to connect to the gatt server, and even broadcast updates. But I can't seem to detect any heart rate. Am I missing something?

Here'y my codes.

```
public class BleActivity extends Activity {

public final static String ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED =
        "com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED";
public final static String ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED =
        "com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED";
public final static String ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED =
        "com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED";
public final static String ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE =
        "com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE";
public final static String EXTRA_DATA =
        "com.example.bluetooth.le.EXTRA_DATA";

private BluetoothDevicesAdapter bluetoothDevicesAdapter;
private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

private static final long SCAN_PERIOD = 5000;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

private BluetoothGatt mGatt;

@Bind(R.id.bleDeviceListView)
ListView listView;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ble);

    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    bluetoothDevicesAdapter = new BluetoothDevicesAdapter(getApplicationContext());
    listView.setAdapter(bluetoothDevicesAdapter);

    final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager =
            (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
    mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();

}

@OnClick(R.id.scanButton)
public void onScanClicked() {

    scanLeDevice();

}

@OnItemClick(R.id.bleDeviceListView)
public void onItemClicked(int position) {

    connectToDevice((BluetoothDevice) bluetoothDevicesAdapter.getItem(position));

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    unregisterReceiver(mGattUpdateReceiver);

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    registerReceiver(mGattUpdateReceiver, makeGattUpdateIntentFilter());

    //CONFIRMS IF BLUETOOTH IS ENABLED
    if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {

            GenericDialogBox.EnableBluetoothBox(BleActivity.this, "Notice", "This app requires bluetooth. Enable?", mBluetoothAdapter);

        }
    }

}

private void scanLeDevice() {

    bluetoothDevicesAdapter.clear();
    bluetoothDevicesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(BleActivity.this);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Scanning Devices");
    progressDialog.show();

    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(leScanCallback);
            progressDialog.hide();
            mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(leScanCallback);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            progressDialog = null;

        }
    }, SCAN_PERIOD);

    mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(leScanCallback);

}

private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback leScanCallback = new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, final int rssi, final byte[] scanRecord) {

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                bluetoothDevicesAdapter.addDevice(device);
                bluetoothDevicesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });

    }
};

public void connectToDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
    if (mGatt == null) {

        mGatt = device.connectGatt(this, false, btleGattCallback);

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(BleActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Connecting to Gatt Server.");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();

    }
}

private final BluetoothGattCallback btleGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
        broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(final BluetoothGatt gatt, final int status, final int newState) {
        String intentAction;
        Log.e("onConnectionStateChange", "Status: " + status);
        switch (newState) {
            case BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED:
                intentAction = ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED;
                Log.e("gattCallback", "STATE_CONNECTED");
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                progressDialog = null;

                broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
                mGatt.discoverServices();

                break;
            case BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED:
                intentAction = ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED;
                Log.e("gattCallback", "STATE_DISCONNECTED");
                BluetoothDevice mDevice = gatt.getDevice();
                mGatt = null;
                broadcastUpdate(intentAction);

                break;
            default:

                Log.e("gattCallback", "STATE_OTHER");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onServicesDiscovered(final BluetoothGatt gatt, final int status) {

        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {

            List<BluetoothGattService> services = gatt.getServices();
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic therm_char;

            for (int i = 0; i < services.size(); i++) {
                therm_char = services.get(i).getCharacteristics().get(0);
                if(therm_char.getUuid().equals(SampleGattAttributes.HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT)){
                    gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(therm_char, true);

                    BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = therm_char.getDescriptor(
                            UUID.fromString(SampleGattAttributes.CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG));
                    descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
                    mGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
                }
            }

            broadcastUpdate(ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED);

            Log.e("gattCallback", "Service discovered" + gatt.getServices() + " Status: " + status);

        } else {
            Log.e("BluetoothServices: ", "onServicesDiscovered received: " + status);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);
        }
    }
};

private void broadcastUpdate(final String action) {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(action);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}

private void broadcastUpdate(final String action,
                             final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(action);

    // This is special handling for the Heart Rate Measurement profile. Data
    // parsing is carried out as per profile specifications.
    if (UUID.fromString(SampleGattAttributes.HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT).equals(characteristic.getUuid())) {
        int flag = characteristic.getProperties();
        int format = -1;
        if ((flag & 0x01) != 0) {
            format = BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT16;
            Log.d("Bluetooth Service: ", "Heart rate format UINT16.");
        } else {
            format = BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT8;
            Log.d("Bluetooth Service: ", "Heart rate format UINT8.");
        }
        final int heartRate = characteristic.getIntValue(format, 1);
        Log.d("Bluetooth Service: ", String.format("Received heart rate: %d", heartRate));
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATA, String.valueOf(heartRate));

    } else {
        // For all other profiles, writes the data formatted in HEX.
        final byte[] data = characteristic.getValue();
        if (data != null && data.length > 0) {
            final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(data.length);
            for(byte byteChar : data)
                stringBuilder.append(String.format("%02X ", byteChar));
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATA, new String(data) + "\n" +
                    stringBuilder.toString());
        }
    }
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}

private final BroadcastReceiver mGattUpdateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        if (ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected to Service.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        } else if (ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected to Service.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else if (ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {

            //Update Connection State

        } else if (ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE.equals(action)) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_DATA), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }
};

private static IntentFilter makeGattUpdateIntentFilter() {
    final IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED);
    intentFilter.addAction(ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED);
    intentFilter.addAction(ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED);
    intentFilter.addAction(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE);
    return intentFilter;
}
```

And this is the sampleAttributes Class.

```
public class SampleGattAttributes {
private static HashMap<String, String> attributes = new HashMap();
public static String HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT = "00002a37-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb";
public static String CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG = "00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb";

static {
    // Sample Services.
    attributes.put("0000180d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "Heart Rate Service");
    attributes.put("0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "Device Information Service");
    // Sample Characteristics.
    attributes.put(HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT, "Heart Rate Measurement");
    attributes.put("00002a29-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "Manufacturer Name String");
}

public static String lookup(String uuid, String defaultName) {
    String name = attributes.get(uuid);
    return name == null ? defaultName : name;
}
```

}

And also is there a way to log if the device is searching for any changes from time to time?

Thank you!

Comment: Hello, I'm facing similar problem, I'm connecting to my BLE device, and listening for the Discovered Services, but there isn't Heart Measurement Service discovered, but there is such funcionality in the bracelet. What to do?
The device i'm using is Fitness tracker V10